# wso2 EMM user / device enrollment issue

Tags: wso2

I am setting up wso2 2.0.1 in my local machine [windows 7], i am able to intall and start server and create users in that but while createing the user profile the email are not getting to the usre to enroll. I did the configurattions expalined below. I am not getting anyy error and getting a message like the invitation mail sent to the user, butt no mails received.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM210/General+Server+Configurations#GeneralServerConfigurations-email.

Can anyyone help on this...

Comment: What type of account have you configured as the smtp is it a yahoo account?

Comment: added gmail account

Answer (score 0):

This can be mainly because the gmail account you are using is preventing the application to send the email. You can check whether 3rd party application support is enabled or disabled in gmail. You can enable 3rd party application access by navigating to **sign-in & security** via settings and enable **Allow less secure apps**: [[1]](https://www.google.com/settings/u/0/security/lesssecureapps)

Comment: I did this, but now the wso2 emm - https://10.4.146.114:9443/emm its not loadinig, seems firewall blocking Itried in diff n/w but the same.Any help on this ,,?